# selecting mirrored edges

Tags: modeling, mirror

I have been following a modeling tutorial, and they had me mirror the legs of the character and merge them at the groin.  Then they want me to select the top loop of the new merged legs, and I can select the edges on the original leg, but the mirrored leg won't let me select anything.  Is there something I'm missing?  I'm fairly new to blender and im sure I'm just missing something.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select mirrored edges. To be able to do *anything* to the mirrored side, you must apply the modifier first, then go back to edit mode.

In 2.79 and before, the "On-clipping" function was not available, but in 2.80+, it allows you to select the mirrored side. It doesn't allow much editing though.

Comment: WOW thank you SOOOOO much!!  I was pulling my hair out over this.  I legit thought I had already done that!

Comment: If this is the correct answer, then please mark it as that for future users of this site.

Comment: you can select mirrored edges by activating "on cage" button of the modifier.

Comment: Not in 2.79 and before.

Comment: Yes you could select  from mirrored side in 2.7x and before  Using the "on cage" button as suggested by @lemon   Btw it's known as the "accepted answer".  Accepted answers are not always correct. (and vice versa)