# Why can't I select mirrored faces?

Tags: modeling, faces, mirror

So I've mirrored the faces to make a mouth, but can't select any of the mirrored faces, it's as if they are ghost faces.

I've tried selecting faces, going into edit mode and object mode, But I'm new to this app so I don't ave a lot of knowledge about it:

[image: picture of the faces not showing up]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165699/selecting-mirrored-edges/165701#165701

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select mirrored faces. If you want to select them, you need to apply the modifier and from this point you can make the 2 half different.